# iOS In-app purchases - Which alerts get displayed automatically?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am working on adding in-app purchases to my iOS app.

Is there a way to know all the possible alerts that Apple will display?

I am testing with sandbox user. I can see that they display "You're all set - your purchase was successful". What else gets displayed? Are the errors displayed as well? Is there documentation about this?

Thanks

Comment: Something like this? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skerror

Comment: I meant, are the errors displayed as well. Or is there just the one success alert. I updated my question for more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to know all the possible alerts that Apple will display?

No, there isn't. The disconnect between what you see when testing and what can happen during the actual purchase is one of the huge flaws in the in-app purchase architecture.

However, you don't *really* need to know this. Everything the runtime will display to the user is out of your process and has no connection with your code. Your job is to implement the observer method(s) correctly, that's all you should do and all you can do.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to know to avoid duplicate alerts e.g. Apple shows an error alert and my app shows an alert based on the error returned. I guess maybe there is no way to know for sure.

Comment: Yeah, that's a big problem for sure. Not to mention that you can't show your alert _while Apple's alert is showing_.